# How do I get access to an actively running script?

Tags: server, 20.04, bash, minecraft

I've rented an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Linode server running my Minecraft server. I've made it so `wrapper.sh` is being run when the server is rebooted/started. However, sometimes I need to access the script to execute commands in the Minecraft server and to do that I'd have to somehow close the script and run it again manually. This is very inconvenient in many ways, how can I make this easier?